# How to verify if vectors are in the same plane

Tags: math

I have a collection of 3D vectors. How do I verify if these Vectors are in the same plane

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about vectors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you should select one of your N points and subtract its coordinates from all the other N-1 point coordinates.  You thus get a collection of N-1 vectors.  The question of whether the N points are in the same plane is equivalent to knowing whether the N-1 vectors are in a plane that goes through the origin.

The determinant of any matrix 3x3 made of three vectors is zero if and only if the three vectors are in the same plane.  You could set two columns to two fixed, non-colinear vectors from your set (this defines a plane that contains the origin), and then check all the other vectors successively by setting the third column of the matrix to their coordinates, calculating its determinant, and checking that it is zero to some precision.  As noted by woodchips, calculating a determinant with a good precision is not completely trivial, so it is best to use a well-tested function, for this (like a function in a matrix package).

Another, computationally faster and more precise approach is to take two of your vectors, make sure that they define a plane (i.e. that they are not colinear), and then calculate their cross product: this gives you a vector normal to the plane.  Then, you can make sure that each other vector is in the same plane by performing a dot product with the normal vector: this dot product is zero only if the new vector is in the same plane as your first two vectors.

You can test whether two vectors are colinear or not by calculating the norm of their cross product: if the norm is not zero (to a given precision), then the vectors are not colinear.

Comment: I would point out that a determinant is not a terribly computationally stable thing. So while this scheme will give some indication of planarity, it carries some potentially significant difficulties with it.

Comment: @woodchips is perfectly right. You should first normalize your vectors and only test for smallness. As an aside, testing the signum of a determinant often yields wrong answers, because of catastrophic cancellation.

Comment: Also, the OP asks for the planarity of a *collection* (ie. > 3) of vectors. The right answer here is SVD. Determinants will get you nowhere.

Comment: @EOL Your second method is sufficient for me now. I chose 3 non-collinear Vectors a, b, c (these 3 Vectors will make my plane P). I calculated the unit normal vector N at a. To verify if vector d is in the plane, I calculated the distance = Dot( d-a, N). Appreciate all of you for your valuable suggestions and Help. Thanks!!

Comment: @Alexandre C: Even though the scalar product method is numerically better, there *are* numerical methods for calculating determinants with precision (NumPy's det() function is one example); it's true that it may be a good idea to normalize vectors first, even with such methods.  Furthermore, the fact that the OP has a *collection* of vectors is perfectly handled by the calculation of a determinant for each vector successively; this method might be faster than a SVD, depending on how many vectors there are, and whether they are expected to often be in a plane or not.

Comment: @Razack: If the "second method is sufficient for me now", the proper thing to do is select EOL's response as the answer.

Comment: @EOL: Properly computing determinants is a matter of exact precision arithmetic (very difficult to do by yourself in C or C++). Also, the right method depends on what tolerance the OP is ready to give.  It is true that the determinant method scales better with the number of vectors, but finding the right plane to check against is very unstable if there is a lot of vectors (and therefore a lot of numerical noise). I maintain that SVD is the right choice in this kind of problems. Randomly checking a few vectors for planarity and performing full SVD if necessary may be a good choice if...

Comment: ...the vectors are not expected to lie in a plane often.

Comment: @Razack: Thanks, I appreciate.  @Alexandre C.: Determinants are often calculated numerically through matrix decomposition methods (LU, QR, etc.), so what you mean by this being "a matter of exact precision arithmetic"? :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Subtract off the mean value of all the vectors.
2. Create an nx3 array of all the vectors, with each row one mean subtracted vector.
3. Compute a singular value decomposition of that array.
4. Test to see if exactly two of the three resulting singular values are significantly larger than the third.

That third singular value should be on the order of 10^-15 as large as the largest singular value. If it is not so, then the vectors do not all lie in a single plane. (This presumes that your work was in double precision. As well, if that ratio is only 1e-13, I'd not complain.)

Comment: Also, the singular vectors corresponding to those two singular values will give you the direction of the plane. You can get a point of the plane (and thus determine it completely) by taking the mean value of the vectors.

Comment: @woodchips: Interesting: do you have a reference that explains why point 4 is equivalent to the points being coplanar?

Comment: Depending on the number of vectors, and how likely it is that the vectors are not coplanar, a full singular value decomposition might be slower than a vector by vector check.  If the vectors all fit in memory and if they are often coplanar, then the SVD should be the fastest approach.

Comment: This comes from the definition of the SVD, along with basic linear algebra. So essentially, a good text on numerical linear algebra that explains what the SVD does would suffice. The SVD reduces the row space (and column space) of your matrix to a linear combination of vectors. If the rowspace has effective rank 2, then your vectors (the rows) MUST all live in a single plane.

Comment: Similarly, if exactly one of those singular values is non-zero compared to the remainder, then all of your vectors must fall along a single line in space. In all cases, there will be degrees of success. For example, consider a case where the singular values are something like this: {1,1e-6,1e-15}. Scale them so the largest singular value is 1. Here the vectors do lie in a single plane, but they also nearly lie along a single line too. That second dimension is very small compared to the first.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer so much as three observations, the first of which is too long to be a comment.

**Observation #1: This problem as stated is ambiguous.**
Two very different meanings are

1. Can each of the N vectors be written in the form aû<sub>1</sub> + bû<sub>2</sub>, where û<sub>1</sub> and û<sub>2</sub> are a pair of unit vectors in 3-space?
2. If the vectors are treated as displacement vectors from the origin, are the points defined by the endpoints of the N vectors coplanar?

To illustrate this ambiguity, consider the three canonical unit vectors xhat, yhat, and zhat. By meaning #1, these three vectors are not coplanar. By meaning #2, they are. It takes three points to define a plane, so three points cannot be non-coplanar. Another example:

- Vector 1 = (5000, 2, 1)
- Vector 2 = (5000, 2, -1)
- Vector 3 = (5000, -2, 1)
- Vector 4 = (5000, -2, -1)

By meaning #1, these vectors are not coplanar but they are by meaning #2.

If the second meaning is the correct interpretation, then doing the subtractions as described in the solutions to date is essential. For example, consider the SVD/PCA solution described by woodchips. Bypassing step 1, "Subtract off the mean value of all the vectors," would result in the SVD finding that xhat is the first principal component.

If the first meaning is the correct interpretation, then doing those subtractions is absolutely the wrong thing to do. Here the SVD should find xhat as the first principal component and should find that there are indeed three significant components.

**Observation #2: On SVD versus iterative solutions**
Suppose you have 5000 vectors at hand. If the 5000 vectors truly are coplanar, the SVD approach will be faster than the iterative approaches. If, on the other hand, looking at the first five vector is sufficient to answer "No", then looking at the remaining 4995 vectors is just silly. Which is the better solution depends on the expectations of whether the answer will typically be "yes, they are coplanar" or "no, they are not coplanar".

**Observation #3: On detection**
Comparing floating point numbers to zero on a computer is usually a bad idea. It is much better to distinguish between small and not small. Here is where the SVD shines: Just look at the ratio of the third principal component to the first. With the iterative solutions it is a bit tougher to distinguish between small versus not small.

Answer (score -1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29) has all the answers you need. 
As you know, 3 points determine a plane. Therefore, if you have 0,1,2, or 3 distinct vectors in your collection, they are on a same plane for certain.

Follow the above link and you will find a way to determine the plane from the first three (distinct) vectors of your collection. And another section tells you how to compute the distance to this plane for the remaining points. If the distance is 0 for all of them, they are in the same plane.

Comment: Checking whether the distance is 0 is slower, but equivalent to checking whether the dot product with a normal vector has a fixed value, which in turn is equivalent to the test "dot product" I suggested.  Furthermore, it is not enough to take three distinct points A, B and C from the collection: they could represent points that are aligned, and therefore do not represent a plane.  The correct selection criterium is that the cross product of vectors AB and AC is not zero.

Answer (score -1):

A simple algorithm:

1. Find the plane that the first two distinct vectors lie in.
2. From all vectors, subtract the projection into this plane.
3. If the result is nonzero for any vector, that vector is not in the same plane.

In detail:

1. Let `v_a = v_1`
2. Let `v_b = v_2 - v_a (v_a dot v_2)`.
   Now `v_b` is orthogonal to `v_a` and `{v_a,v_b}` forms an orthonormal basis for the plane.
3. For all vectors `v_i`, compute `v_i' = v_i - v_a (v_i dot v_a) - v_b (v_i dot v_b)`.
   If this `v_i'` is nonzero for any vector, then that vector does not lie in the same plane as vectors `v_1` and `v_2`.

This algorithm assumes that you are interested in the plane containing both the origin and the ends of all the vectors.  If instead you are thinking about a collection of points rather than a collection of vectors, simply subtract the mean of all the points from each point first.

This is basically a variant of the [Gram-Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) for making an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Finding the initial plane (step 1) is not as simple as finding "the first two distinct vectors", as they might be distinct but colinear.

Comment: The "3 coordinates, double dot product" approach (step B.3) is much slower than simply calculating the dot product with a vector normal to the plane and checking whether it is zero.